# Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions. Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store: https://aka.ms/wslstore

Tags: linux, mongodb, windows, version

I was installing MongoDB on Windows.

1. I installed Mongo using:
   npm install -g m
2. Then when I was trying to install the latest version of Mongo using:
   m latest

I got this message:
**Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore**

I tried: mongod --version to check if Mongo has been installed but I got this message:
**'mongod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**